# Is there any specific license should be used for Google Drive SDK?

Tags: licensing, google-drive-api

Is it compatible with Apache License Version 2.0?

Though it have samples used Apache license, couldn't find any documentation of sdk which officially mentioned about the license.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange, but **read their faq carefully** before proceeding.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java SDK code is hosted at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

It is stated there as Apache 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I think it is "Apache License, Version 2.0" only.

Read the terms for the same : https://developers.google.com/terms/

Comment: I already go through with that. But it don't mentioned clearly about the licensing. Anyway thanks for the reply.